# SQL Convert Week Number to Date (dd/MM)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to convert the week number (*for example: **21***) in SQL-Server to the date (from the Monday of that week) in **dd/MM** format.

I have searched online but cannot seem to find anything that I could use.

***Is this something I can do?***

Any help or advice is appreciated.

**Thank you in advance.**

Comment: Can you clarify your goal? Are you just need to get date of Monday of wht week having number N?

Comment: Yes that's correct @AndyKorneyev

Comment: and the current year if possible @bmsqldev

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this,

```
declare @wk int  set @wk = 21
declare @yr int  set @yr = 2016

select dateadd (week, @wk-1, dateadd (year, @yr-1900, 0)) - 4 -
       datepart(dw, dateadd (week, @wk-1, dateadd (year, @yr-1900, 0)) - 4) + 1
```

or try this way

```
declare @wk int  = 21

select dateadd(week,@wk-1, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,-1,DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,getdate()), 0)), 0))
```

Comment: First way with @ wk = 1 and @ yr = 2017 returns 2016-12-25. Seems that converting first weeknumber to date is invalid operion at all, imho

Comment: Similar to the above comment, set @wk=10,@yr=2021, returns 2021-02-25 which is incorrect.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it something like:

```
declare @Week_Number int, @Year int, @Year_Start_Day date, @Week_Day date

select 
    @Week_Number = 1,
    @Year = 2016

select @Year_Start_Day = cast(@Year as nvarchar(4)) + '0101'
select @Week_Day =  dateadd(wk, @Week_Number, @Year_Start_Day)

select dateadd(dd, 1 - datepart(weekday, @Week_Day), @Week_Day)
```

Comment: maybe, but with @Year = 2017 it returns "2017-01-08"

Comment: but changing "1" to "0" in last row will help ) Thanks for working solution

Answer (score 1):

This will do:

```
DECLARE @y int = 2016,
        @w int = 21

SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar(5),DATEADD(day,@w*7-(DATEPART(WEEKDAY,CAST(@y as nvarchar(4))+'-01-01')-2),CAST(@y as nvarchar(4))+'-01-01'),3)
```

Output:

```
23/05
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
DECLARE @YearNum SMALLINT = 2016;
DECLARE  @WeekNum TINYINT=25;

select 
    SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),selected_date,105),0,6) AS WeeKDate
from 
(select DATEADD(dd,t4.i*10000 + t3.i*1000 + t2.i*100 + t1.i*10 + t0.i,'1970-01-01') selected_date from
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4) v
where YEAR(selected_date)=@YearNum
AND DATEPART(WK,selected_date)=@WeekNum
AND DATEPART(WEEKDAY,selected_date)=2 -- Monday
```