# Convert Week Name to Date SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, date

I am trying to convert the week numbers to actual dates based on my query:

Example: `week 1 2017` should be converted to `January 2, 2017`

```
SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar(10),DATEADD(day,DATEPART(WEEK,[DeliveryDate])*7-(DATEPART(WEEKDAY,CAST(DATEPART(YEAR,[DeliveryDate]) as nvarchar(4))+'-01-01')-2),CAST(DATEPART(YEAR,[DeliveryDate]) as nvarchar(4))+'-01-01'),126) AS week_name,
AVG(DATEDIFF(day, CONVERT(date, [UnloadDate]), CONVERT(date, [DeliveryDate]))) as Average_Delivery_Days FROM [CARGODB].[dbo].[Cargo_Transactions] 
WHERE [DeliveryDate] IS NOT NULL AND [DeliveryDate] != 0 
AND [UnloadDate] IS NOT NULL AND [UnloadDate] != 0 AND [DeliveryDate] > [UnloadDate] 
AND [Deleted] = 0 and [StageID] = 'D' AND [RouteID] IS NOT NULL AND [RouteID] != '' AND CONVERT(date, [DeliveryDate]) BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND GETDATE()
AND CONVERT(date, [DeliveryDate]) >= DATEADD(week, -24, getdate()) GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR,[DeliveryDate]), DATEPART(WEEK,[DeliveryDate]) ORDER BY DATEPART(YEAR,[DeliveryDate]) ASC, DATEPART(WEEK,[DeliveryDate]) ASC;
```

This part:

```
CONVERT(nvarchar(10),DATEADD(day,DATEPART(WEEK,[DeliveryDate])*7-(DATEPART(WEEKDAY,CAST(DATEPART(YEAR,[DeliveryDate]) as nvarchar(4))+'-01-01')-2),CAST(DATEPART(YEAR,[DeliveryDate]) as nvarchar(4))+'-01-01'),126)
```

came from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37480952/sql-convert-week-number-to-date-dd-mm).

But I check my data and I think it's not correct. I compared one to an [Epoch Converter](https://www.epochconverter.com/weeks/2017). For example: `week 25 2017` should be `June 19, 2017` but it's displaying `June 26, 2017` and when I checked the date in the Epoch converter, it should be `week 26 2017` and so on.

**UPDATE**

I have found a way to get what I want having this part:

```
CONVERT(varchar(10),dateadd (week, DATEPART(WEEK, [DeliveryDate]), dateadd (year, DATEPART(YEAR, [DeliveryDate])-1900, 0)) - 4 - datepart(dw, dateadd (week, DATEPART(WEEK, [DeliveryDate]), dateadd (year, DATEPART(YEAR, [DeliveryDate])-1900, 0)) - 4) + 1, 126)
```

It gives me the week dates as Sundays but I want the week to start on Mondays so I added `SET DATEFIRST 1`. But right after adding it to my query, it forwards to the next monday. I was expecting it to be: `June 18, 2017 (Sunday)` into `June 19, 2017 (Monday)` but I get `June 26, 2017 (Monday)` instead.

What's wrong with my query?

Comment: No, check the Epoch Converter again. `Week 25 2017` is `June 19, 2017`. So use this query. `declare @wk int  = 25
select dateadd(week,@wk-1, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,-1,DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,getdate()), 0)), 0)) `

Comment: Thanks @WEI_DBA for your answer. It produced the right answer for 2017. But what if I need to get a different year? Sorry for the trouble and thanks for your help!

Comment: Change `getdate()` to the date you want.

Answer (score 0):

this is just and example on what i understood.
you can give various sample data and explain your outout.

```
    declare @i varchar(50)='week 1 2017'

      select weekNumber,FOY,dateadd(day,-6,dateadd(week,cast(weekNumber as int),cast(FOY as datetime)))ReqDate
 from
 (
select substring(ltrim(replace(@i,'week','')),0,CHARINDEX(' ',ltrim(replace(@i,'week','')))) weekNumber,
right(@i,4) +'-01-01'FOY

)t4
```