# Week number to Date SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Any idea to convert this varchar:

201751

value to a date value in SQL:

2017-12-18

Comment: What platform?  What does 51 define?

Comment: MS SQL Server 2014 ... 51 means week number

Comment: @PabloGûereca Then add SQL Server tag to your question!!!!!

Comment: @PabloGûereca What have you tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Convert Week Number to Date (dd/MM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37480952/sql-convert-week-number-to-date-dd-mm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made a couple variables to parse out the year and week. Then using `DATEDIFF` to calculate the week and then `DATEADD` to add the weeks to that value and present the date.

```
DECLARE @InputValue as varchar(6) = '201751';
DECLARE @YearNum as varchar(4) = LEFT(@InputValue,4);
DECLARE @WeekNum as varchar(2) = RIGHT(@InputValue,2);

SELECT DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, '1/1/' + @YearNum) + (@WeekNum-1), 6) AS StartOfWeek,
       DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 5, '1/1/' + @YearNum) + (@WeekNum-1), 5) AS EndOfWeek;
```

Result:

```
 StartOfWeek                EndOfWeek
 2017-12-17 00:00:00.000    2017-12-23 00:00:00.000
```

Note that this will only work for your 6 character string input where the first 4 characters are the year and the last *two* characters are the month.