# select this week plus 7 weeks forward?

Tags: sql-server, while-loop, insert, datepart

I have a table that looks like this:

[image]

```
SELECT
      [Year],
      [Week]
FROM [BI_Planning].[dbo].[tblWeekCalendar]
```

I have manually set the records from 1 week 15 of 2018.

i would like to have a select that gives me this week (15) + 7 weeks forward
something like this:

[image]

However when week 16 comes then i should have week 16 + 7 that would mean one new row 2018 - 23

Year have to come in to play here also because when the end of the year is i would like to have 2019 - 1 and so in.

To get the week im in i use `select datepart(iso_week,getdate())`

Is this possible?

Comment: related questoin https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37480952/sql-convert-week-number-to-date-dd-mm

Once you convert week number+year to a date, you can easily calculate date range and use that in a WHERE clause

Comment: The answer also depends on how you define a week number, there are multiple ways to do that.

Comment: This gets me the week im in select datepart(iso_week,getdate())

Comment: It gets tricky at the end of the year.  December 30th, gives week 53 in SQL Server. `SELECT DATEPART(week, '2018-12-30')`.  Because there are 52.1429 weeks in a year, Dec 30th is technically past week 52 and starting into 53.  Would you consider week 53 valid?

Answer (score 1):

Instead on inserting manually or adding 7 to calculate the week numbers, you should use the default SQL Function `DATEPART` to get the correct week number.

You can generate weeks within a date range like following.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '2018-01-01'
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = '2019-12-31' 

SELECT DISTINCT  DATEPART( wk, T1.DATE) AS [Week],Year(T1.DATE)
FROM   (
         SELECT
         @StartDate + RN AS DATE 
        FROM   (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() 
                         OVER ( 
                           ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) RN 
                FROM   master..[spt_values]) T) T1 
WHERE  T1.DATE <= @EndDate 
ORDER BY Year(T1.DATE)
```

If you want WeekStart and WeekEnd also, you can try like following.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '2018-01-01'
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = '2019-12-31' 

SELECT MIN(T1.DATE) WeekStart, MAX(T1.DATE) WeekEnd, [Week], [Year]
FROM
(
    SELECT  DATEPART( wk, T1.DATE) AS [Week],Year(T1.DATE) AS [Year], T1.DATE
    FROM   (
            SELECT
            @StartDate + RN AS DATE 
        FROM   (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() 
                            OVER ( 
                            ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) RN 
                FROM   master..[spt_values]) T) T1 
    WHERE  T1.DATE <= @EndDate 

) T1
GROUP BY [Week], [Year]
ORDER BY [Year],[Week]
```

Comment: Like I said in my comment though, there's multiple ways to calculate week numbers, this shows only one of them. It also doesn't account for which day of the week it starts.

Comment: The day of the week in monday

Comment: @Nils what do you mean by monday, you are getting max and min date, you can convert it to day name easily.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below approach

```
DECLARE @Weekstart int = DATEPART(WW, '2018-01-01')
DECLARE @WeekEnd int = DATEPART(WW, '2018-12-31')

CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
Year int,
WeekNo int
)
INSERT INTO #Temp (Year, WeekNo) VALUES (DATEPART(YYYY, GETDATE()),1)

DECLARE @Count INT
DECLARE @TotalCount INT
SET @TotalCount = DATEPART(WW, '2018-12-31')
SET @Count = 1

WHILE (@Count < @TotalCount)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @WeekNo INT
    SELECT @WeekNo = MAX(ISNULL(WeekNo, 0))+1 FROM #Temp
    INSERT INTO #Temp (Year, WeekNo) VALUES (DATEPART(YYYY, GETDATE()),@WeekNo)
    SET @Count = @Count+1
END

INSERT INTO #Temp (Year, WeekNo) VALUES (DATEPART(YYYY, GETDATE())+1,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to address how you want to handle say the transition from 2015 to 2016. You could use code such as this for example to help address your 7 week look-forward:

```
DECLARE @start date;
DECLARE @end date;
DECLARE @year int;
DECLARE @week int;

SET @start = '1/1/2015';
SET @end = '12/31/2030';

SET @year = 2016;
SET @week = 50;

WITH cte AS (
SELECT Year(@start) AS Year
    , 1 AS Week
    , @start AS CurDate
    , 1 AS WeekID
UNION ALL
SELECT Year(DATEADD(dd, 7, CurDate))
    , DATEPART(wk, (CASE WHEN DATEPART(dy, DATEADD(dd, 7, CurDate)) <= 7 THEN '1/1/' + CONVERT(varchar, Year(DATEADD(dd, 7, CurDate))) ELSE DATEADD(dd, 7, CurDate) END))
    , (CASE WHEN DATEPART(dy, DATEADD(dd, 7, CurDate)) <= 7 THEN '1/1/' + CONVERT(varchar, Year(DATEADD(dd, 7, CurDate))) ELSE DATEADD(dd, 7, CurDate) END)
    , WeekID + 1
FROM cte
WHERE DATEADD(dd, 7, CurDate) <= @end
)

SELECT Year, Week
FROM cte
WHERE WeekID <= (SELECT x.WeekID FROM cte x WHERE x.Year = @Year AND x.Week = @Week) + 7
AND Year IN (@Year, @Year + 1)
OPTION (maxrecursion 0)
```

This assumes you're okay with "resetting" to Jan 1 at the start of each year - if you do a true 7 day rolling forward, you can get into wonky scenarios (e.g. missing week 1 from some years, like 2016).