# SQL Server 2008 week number conversion to actual date

Tags: sql-server

I have a column in one of my db tables that is labeled as weeks. I am working on some visuals with sisense and it would make things a lot easier if I have an actual date instead of a week number and a month/year. My goal is to create a new column with converted values  (week # 1, January, 2019 converted to Dec 31, 2018/12-31-18 * Monday would be the start day of the week *).

Hopefully that makes sense because I am terrible at explaining things

I am not 100% on what info could be needed since I am just using just a generic example but I will be more than happy to try and supply anything you might need within reason

Comment: Look here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/37481211/12188861

Comment: If you think this is a duplicate, you should flag it as one, @basic .

Comment: @basic  I believe that was just converting it for that single use. I am needing it to convert it entirely. I am fine with those still being columns but I don't want to have to run a query everytime I need to fiddle with things. Also this is a 7 year range that I am changing. I would think it would need to run all at once instead of by year that way there is no mixup with the date changes every year

Answer (score 0):

My link doesn't directly solve your problem, but it show you how to convert a week number to a date. If you need to convert value 'week # 1, January, 2019' to a date, you can use following example:

```
declare @yw varchar(25) = 'week # 1, January, 2019'
declare @y char(4)=RIGHT(@yw,4)
declare @wnum int=SUBSTRING(@yw,8,CHARINDEX(',',@yw,0)-8)

select  dateadd(week,@wnum-1, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,-1,DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,@y+'-01-01'), 0)), 0))
```

To convert values into a table, simply replace the variable names with the column names