# How to get start date and end date by selecting week number in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, calendar

I face a scenario where I have to get the start day and end day of a particular Week Number. The week day starts with Saturday and Ends Thursday.

Suppose I give a week number 40, output will be start date 26th Sept 2020 and end date will be 01st October.

I use

```
set datefirst 6 
select datepart(week, getdate()) WeekNo
```

to find out the week number - week starts from Saturday.

Comment: _Especially_ if you have a nonstandard "week" like this, you want to look into creating what's known as a calendar table (which would allow you to just look up the dates in the table).  Of course, that doesn't help if you're trying to create one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to a week number, you will need to include a year number:

```
declare @wk int  set @wk = 40
declare @yr int  set @yr = 2020

select dateadd (week, @wk-1, dateadd (year, @yr-1900, 0)) - 4 -
       datepart(dw, dateadd (week, @wk-1, dateadd (year, @yr-1900, 0)) - 4) + 1 StartDate,
    dateadd (week, @wk-1, dateadd (year, @yr-1900, 0)) - 4 -
       datepart(dw, dateadd (week, @wk-1, dateadd (year, @yr-1900, 0)) - 4) + 6 EndDate

StartDate               EndDate
2020-09-26 00:00:00.000 2020-10-01 00:00:00.000
```

Slightly modified from this great answer: [SQL Convert Week Number to Date (dd/MM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37480952/sql-convert-week-number-to-date-dd-mm)

Comment: Not that I don't believe this will work, I'm just a little concerned about something using a non-standard week.  More particularly, `datepart(dw ...)` is dependent on what the cultural settings are (and, alas, there isn't an iso-day-of-week).

Comment: Week is user defined. "set datepart 6" gives a week calculation starts with saturday and ends thursday. According to this arrangement the answer is 100% correct.