# SQL - Transform Week String into date format

Tags: sql, date, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using SQL in Snowflake and would like to transform a column that has dates in a string format: '2023 W37' into a date format, always giving me the date ('YYYY-MM-DD') of the Monday in this week. In this case: '2023-11-09'.

I tried working with substring, but cannot get to the required result :(

Thanks for any help!
Michelle

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37480952/sql-convert-week-number-to-date-dd-mm

Answer (score -1):

You can perform the following steps:

1. split your string into constituent parts
2. cast your year to a date
3. use `DATE_ADD(week, )` to add the split out weeks to the year date
4. use `DATE_TRUNC(week,`  to truncate the date to the week start date:

---

```
SELECT '2023 W37' weekdate, 
    DATE_TRUNC(week, dateadd(week, SPLIT_PART(weekdate, ' W', 2), TRY_TO_DATE(SPLIT_PART(weekdate, ' W', 1), 'YYYY')))
```

Comment: I'm so glad to hear that did the trick!